# Synchronizing Git and Svn

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I have a SVN repository and I used:

```
git svn clone <svn url>
```

I have also created a repository on github. So every time I push the changes to github I would also commit the changes back to SVN.

```
git svn dcommit
```

Everything worked fine until my harddisk crashed. Now I need to restore a working copy of my source code. I can think of two ways of doing it:

1. Clone the repository from SVN and add github as the remote. How do I add information about the github repository?
2. Clone from github and then add the information about SVN manually? How do I add information about the SVN repo?

NOTE: *I know the title of the question doesn't make sense. But I really don't know what to name it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with option 1.

You could:

- re-clone your svn repo into a Git one, generating informations about the SVN repo in your local Git repo

  ```
  git svn clone svn://my/svn/repo -T trunk -b branches -t tags
  ```
- add github information by:

  ```
  git remote add github git@github.com:git_username/projectname.git
  ```

Comment: I think option 1 is actually the *only* way to go. I don't think it's possible to add the necessary git-svn metadata *after* commits have already been added to the repository.

Comment: @Dan: agreed. This is why I went with option 1.